# Как пропускать файлы занятые процессом

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Использую цикл:

```
for file in filebrowse:
    if os.access(file, os.R_OK and os.X_OK):
        os.remove(file)
```

Когда он проходит по файлам, я проверяю его на доступность строкой:

```
if os.access(file, os.R_OK and os.X_OK):
```

Выдает ошибку:

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом:

Как пропустить файл, который занят и продолжить удаление файлов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто ловите исключение [PermissionError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#PermissionError):

```
for file in filebrowse:
    try:
        if os.access(file, os.R_OK and os.X_OK):
            os.remove(file)
    except PermissionError:
        pass
```